# Product collection has no name attribute how can I get it magento2?

Tags: magento2, product

I tried this code but :-

```
$product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));


     echo '<pre>'; print_r($product->getData()); echo '<pre/>'; die();

             Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 36
                [attribute_set_id] => 11
                [type_id] => simple
                [sku] => 24-MG04
                [has_options] => 0
                [required_options] => 0
                [created_at] => 2016-08-21 07:56:06
                [updated_at] => 2016-08-21 07:56:06
            )
    )
```

And I am getting this result except of all the attributes.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98945/magento-2-how-can-i-get-all-product-attributes-and-get-the-value-yes-no

Comment: have you worked using below method?

Comment: <?php foreach($product as $pr) {echo $pr->getName();}

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory` as a factory object and after setting it in constructor use

```
$collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(
        'name'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'sku'
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        'price'
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'entity_id', array('in' => $productIds)
    );
```

Also refer to this link 
[Magento 2: to use or not to use the ObjectManager directly?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly)

Answer (score 0):

Inside block file,

```
<?php

public function getProductInfo(){
         $product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
  return $product;
}
```

You have to just call inside your template files, When you can iterate loop inside template file its will display name,

```
<?php 
$productsData = $block->getProductInfo();
foreach($productsData as $product){
  echo $product->getName();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `addAttributeToSelect(array('*'))` to get all attributes of product

```
$product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('*'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
```